# Eclipse JVM Terminates Exit Code 1 (Mavericks X.9.2)

Tags: eclipse, jvm, osx-mavericks, exit-code

Great Community

I am getting this JVM Terminated Error {exit code 1} when I am running the Stanford version of Eclipse..

Ive read multiple post.. but I haven't been able to produce positive results...

Any ideas or suggestions that might allow me to get this program running?

Comment: This usually means mixing 32 and 64 bit Eclipse and Java. Since Mavericks only has 64 bit Java you need to download a 64 bit Eclipse.

Comment: will this work with the Stanford version of eclipse? or is there a way to use a more recent version of eclipse and then import the components that allow me to use the assignments that are available for the CS106 A PM Class?

Comment: Sorry, I know nothing about the Stanford Eclipse